# using array to insert all objects that are already declared

Tags: c

I have school assignment which consists in creating a program that does math operation with `Matrix`. In this program, I have to create `Matrix` using `typedef`.

This `typedef` should hold `4 x 4` `Matrix` with `double` type.

So for this here is my implementation:

```
typedef struct {
    char * name;
    double * data;
    int elements;
} mat;
```

In main, I need to define several `mat` objects this way:

```
mat MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C, MAT_D, MAT_E, MAT_F;
```

And this user should type its input for example: `add_mat mat_a,mat_b,mat_c`,
this operation will add 2 `Matrix` `mat_a` and `mat_b` into `mat_c`.

So after that this user input and split it with `Comma\Tab`, I want to write simple function that gets a `char` which is the required `mat` and returns the relevant `mat`:

For example:

```
mat getmatrix(char name, mat *mats)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(mats[i].name, "MAT_A") == 0)
        {
            return mats[i];
        }
    }

    .....
}
```

For this, I insert all my mat objects into `array`:

```
mat mats[] = { MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C, MAT_D, MAT_E, MAT_F };
```

But I get this error for all my `mat` *objects*:

> uninitialized local variable 'MAT_A' used

Any suggestions on how to fix it or maybe find another way to read the input?

Comment: Any suggestion how to fix it ? => there is no `MAT_A` in your code =>
 [mcve].

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: If the matrix size is 4x4, no point in making the elements a pointer. Just put `double data[4][4];` in the structure to simplify things a lot.

Comment: And, further to what @unwind said, you should do the same with the matrix name (use `char name[MAX_NAME];` for some maximum name size), which then means you don't have to do any dynamic memory allocation to use one of your matrices.  That makes life easier — while the array is a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

The way you write it, `mats` would contain **copies** of MAT_A etc. This is not what you want.

Your `getmatrix` function also returns a copy of a matrix. You don't really need it (and copying structs that contain pointers is dangerous; but see below). You probably want to return the matrix *by pointer*, and also accept matrix parameters in all functions by pointer.

I suggest getting rid of `MAT_A` and friends as you don't really need them. Use *only* `mats[i]`. You need to specify the number of elements in `mats`:

```
mat mats[10];
```

Don't forget to initialise `mats` properly.

If for some ungodly reason you are required to define 10 or so different variables of type `mat`, you need to change `mats` to be an array of pointers (yes the common theme here is pointers, you have to use them everywhere).

```
mat* mats[] = { &MAT_A, &MAT_B, /* etc */ };
```

Change `getmatrix` accordingly.

Another thing to consider: if your matrix dimension is fixed, you are using pointers with no reason.  Declaring `double data[4][4]` will simplify things considerably. Same thing about `name`, consider making it a fixed-size character array.

Comment: But the problem is that i have to declare this  MAT_A etc, this is the requirements

Comment: @DannyNitman You need to quote your official requirements verbatim, otherwise it would be rather difficult to guess them.